# Halo Reach to Halo 3 controller mapping

Tags: halo-reach, halo-3

I play a lot of Halo Reach multiplayer and the controls are second nature to me.  Some friends want to have a Halo 3 night and the controls are very similar, but still just enough different that I'm not doing what I want to be doing during critical times in a fight.  Is there a controller configuration in Halo 3 that is equivalent to the default controller configuration in Halo Reach?  I know there are obvious features that are not included in Halo 3 that cannot be mapped, so ideally I'd like for those buttons to be as useless as possible

Comment: If you were to get used to 'Green Thumb', where melee is achieved by clicking down the right analog stick, you would see that it's very similar in all of the Halo games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the controls only differ in the fact that `B` is melee, and `RB` is change grenades.

Also, there's no Halo 3 mapping that's similar to the default Halo Reach mapping. If it was the other way around it'd be different. The `Recon` Mapping in Halo Reach is similar to the Default Halo 3 mapping.

The closest you *will* get is the default Halo 3 mapping.

This is all going based on memory though (I'm currently lending my Halo 3 copy to a friend), so I could be incorrect (I'll let you know when I get my copy back).

Comment: That's the button that keeps getting me killed because I keep changing grenades when close to another player.

Comment: I use the default controls for Halo Reach, but for Halo 3 I use Bumper Jumper. It'll put melee back on right bumper, all you have to get used to is jump on left bumper (imagine you're always using a jetpack) and reload on B (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Try the Walkie Talkie layout in Halo 2. It's pretty much the same as the default layout in Halo Reach.